# WebLogic 10.3.3 .war deployment

Tags: java, war, weblogic-10.x

I have a .war file to deploy that receives the following exception while trying to start.  It loads and installs just fine in Tomcat 7 or 8.  I've tried setting preferred package in weblogic.xml to org.apache.cxf.* and set prefer-web-inf-classes to true with no luck.  Any help, ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
weblogic.application.ModuleException: [HTTP:101216]Servlet: "org.apache.cxf.ws.discovery.internal.WSDiscoveryServiceImpl$WSDiscoveryProvider" failed to preload on startup in Web application: "Proxy.war".
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.lang.InstantiationException: org.apache.cxf.ws.discovery.internal.WSDiscoveryServiceImpl$WSDiscoveryProvider
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSInstanceResolver.getSingleton(WLSInstanceResolver.java:36)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSInstanceResolver.start(WLSInstanceResolver.java:55)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSInstanceResolver$WLSInvoker.start(WLSInstanceResolver.java:82)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.InvokerTube.setEndpoint(InvokerTube.java:85)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.EndpointAwareLateInitTube.postCreateEndpoint(EndpointAwareLateInitTube.java:48)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSServlet.registerEndpoint(JAXWSServlet.java:153)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSServlet.init(JAXWSServlet.java:67)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSDeployedServlet.init(JAXWSDeployedServlet.java:54)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:241)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:283)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.createServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:64)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.createOneInstance(StubLifecycleHelper.java:58)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:48)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.prepareServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:539)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadServlet(WebAppServletContext.java:1985)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.loadServletsOnStartup(WebAppServletContext.java:1959)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1878)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3153)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1508)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:482)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:200)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:247)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:27)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:636)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:205)
    at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:43)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:161)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:569)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.StartOperation.doCommit(StartOperation.java:140)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:323)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:844)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1253)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:440)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:163)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:528)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:207)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:176)
Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.lang.InstantiationException: org.apache.cxf.ws.discovery.internal.WSDiscoveryServiceImpl$WSDiscoveryProvider
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSServletInstanceResolver.create(WLSServletInstanceResolver.java:37)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSInstanceResolver.getSingleton(WLSInstanceResolver.java:34)
```

Okay, so I added the following in the weblogic.xml file and the initial exception is gone. However, the service stays in "start Running" state.

```
<wls:package-name>com.ctc.wstx.*</wls:package-name>
<wls:package-name>org.apache.cxf.*</wls:package-name>
```

And now the following exception occurs.

```
Jan 20, 2015 4:05:24 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
Jan 20, 2015 4:05:24 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext@3aa3a481: display name [Root WebApplicationContext]; startup date [Tue Jan 20 16:05:24 EST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
Jan 20, 2015 4:05:24 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [beans.xml]
Jan 20, 2015 4:05:24 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml]
Jan 20, 2015 4:05:24 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml]
Jan 20, 2015 4:05:25 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext obtainFreshBeanFactory
INFO: Bean factory for application context [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext@3aa3a481]: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@32f989fa
Jan 20, 2015 4:05:25 PM org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport loadProperties
INFO: Loading properties file from class path resource [config.properties]
Jan 20, 2015 4:05:25 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@32f989fa: defining beans [cxf,org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusWiringBeanFactoryPostProcessor,org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.Jsr250BeanPostProcessor,org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusExtensionPostProcessor,propertyConfigurer,PortalsInterface,PortalsImpl,PortalsParameter,PortalsPortalMode,endPointHttpHelper]; root of factory hierarchy
Jan 20, 2015 4:05:25 PM org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean buildServiceFromClass
INFO: Creating Service {http://integration.ellucian.com/}PortalsServiceImplService from class com.ellucian.integration.PortalsInterface
Jan 20, 2015 4:05:26 PM org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl initDestination
INFO: Setting the server's publish address to be /PortalsProxy
Jan 20, 2015 4:06:27 PM org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean isEmptywsdl
WARNING: Failed to parse WSDL
javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=OTHER_ERROR: Error importing schemas: java.io.InterruptedIOException: Connection establishment timed out
    at oracle.j2ee.ws.wsdl.extensions.schema.SchemaSerializer.unmarshall(SchemaSerializer.java:76)
    at oracle.j2ee.ws.wsdl.extensions.ParseUtils.createExtensibilityElement(ParseUtils.java:112)
    at oracle.j2ee.ws.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseTypes(WSDLReaderImpl.java:1483)
    at oracle.j2ee.ws.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseDefinition(WSDLReaderImpl.java:790)
    at oracle.j2ee.ws.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(WSDLReaderImpl.java:707)
    at oracle.j2ee.ws.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(WSDLReaderImpl.java:321)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.loadDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:261)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.getDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:206)
    .....
    .....
    Caused by: java.io.InterruptedIOException: Connection establishment timed out
    at HTTPClient.HTTPConnection.getSocket(HTTPConnection.java:3642)
    at HTTPClient.HTTPConnection.doConnect(HTTPConnection.java:4364)
    at HTTPClient.HTTPConnection.access$3600(HTTPConnection.java:214)
    at HTTPClient.HTTPConnection$11.run(HTTPConnection.java:4338)
    at HTTPClient.HttpClientConfiguration.doAction(HttpClientConfiguration.java:666)
    at HTTPClient.HTTPConnection.doAction(HTTPConnection.java:5401)
    at HTTPClient.HTTPConnection.connect(HTTPConnection.java:4333)
    ......
    ......
    Jan 20, 2015 4:06:27 PM org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean buildServiceFromClass
INFO: Creating Service {http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-dd/ns/discovery/2009/01}Discovery from class org.apache.cxf.ws.discovery.internal.WSDiscoveryServiceImpl$WSDiscoveryProvider
Jan 20, 2015 4:06:27 PM org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl initDestination
INFO: Setting the server's publish address to be soap.udp://239.255.255.250:3702
Jan 20, 2015 4:07:27 PM org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean isEmptywsdl
WARNING: Failed to parse WSDL
```

Comment: Are there any lines before or after regarding the endpoint being incorrect? It sounds more like a setup issue than multiple versions of the same jar, which is what the prefer-web-inf would correct

Comment: Correct, no multiple jar problem, just put that out there that I checked that already, saw that happen before.

Comment: Nothing else in there about the endpoint.  My first intinct was it could a setup issue, but couldn't figure it out after trial and error.  I will toy around with setup again to be sure and exhaust all possibilites.